# React disable/enable selection via radio input

Tags: reactjs

can someone help, I have a component that has **two Radio inputs** that have **two dropdown selections** and I would like the dropdown selection to be disabled/enabled when either of the radio inputs is checked. How do I implement this in a function component?

Radio inputs:

1. Gender is checked by default.
   1.1- Has a gender dropdown selection enabled by default as the initial Gender is checked by default, I want to disable it if the user checks radio input 2. tshirt.
2. T-shirt.
   2.1- Has a t-shirt size dropdown selection should be disabled but can be enabled if the user checks tshirt radio input.

Example:

```
import React from "react";
 
export function Services({ params, updateServices }) {
  const services = params.services;
 
  function HandleChangeValue(event) {
    updateServices({ ...services, [event.target.id]: event.target.value });
  }
 
return (

  //****
  // 1. Gender Radio Input is checked by default
  //****
  <div className="radio">
   <input
     id="gender"
     name="gender"
     type="radio"
     value={services.gender === "gender"}
     defaultChecked
     onChange={HandleChangeValue}
   />
   <label htmlFor="gender">Gender</label>
  </div>
 
 //****
 // 2. T-shirt Radio input
 //****
 <div className="radio">
   <input 
     id="tshirt"
     name="tshirt"
     type="radio" 
     value={services.tshirt === "tshirt"}
     onChange={HandleChangeValue}
   />
   <label htmlFor="tshirt">T-shirts</label>
 </div>
 
 //****
 //Gender dropdown selection is enabled by default, I want to disable it if the user checks tshirt radio input.
 //****
 <div className="">
   <select
     id="gender"
     onChange={HandleChangeValue}
     value={services.gender}
   >
     <option value="female">Some Label</option>
     <option value="male">Some Label</option>
     <option value="other">Some Label</option>
   </select>
 </div>

//****
//T-shirt dropdown size selection to disabled can be enabled if tshirt radio button is checked.
//****
<div className="">
   <select
     id="tshirt"
     onChange={HandleChangeValue}
     value={services.tshirt}
   >
     <option value="s">Some Label</option>
     <option value="ml">Some Label</option>
     <option value="xl">Some Label</option>
   </select>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `disabled` attribute in the select for enabling/disabling and bind with selected radio value.

Please refer the below code for functional component:-

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Radio = () => {
    const [selectedRadio, setSelectedRadio] = useState("gender");

    const HandleChangeValue = (e) => {
        setSelectedRadio(e.target.value);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="radio">
                <input
                    id="gender"
                    name="radioButton"
                    type="radio"
                    value={"gender"}
                    defaultChecked
                    onChange={HandleChangeValue}
                />
                <label htmlFor="gender">Gender</label>
            </div>
            <div className="radio">
                <input
                    id="tshirt"
                    name="radioButton"
                    type="radio"
                    value={"tshirt"}
                    onChange={HandleChangeValue}
                />
                <label htmlFor="tshirt">T-shirts</label>
            </div>

            <div className="">
                <select disabled={selectedRadio === "tshirt"}>
                    <option value="female">Some Label</option>
                    <option value="male">Some Label</option>
                    <option value="other">Some Label</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div className="">
                <select id="tshirt" disabled={selectedRadio === "gender"}>
                    <option value="s">Some Label</option>
                    <option value="ml">Some Label</option>
                    <option value="xl">Some Label</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Radio;
```

Comment: Thanks @Durgesh, your solution works well for my needs.